# Customize ModalDialog component in wicket

Tags: java, modal-dialog, wicket

I have multiple ModalDialogs on one page and each of them should have different width. The customization of each modal dialog can be made in **.CSS** where will be overwritten class **`.modal-dialog`**

I would like to know how I can set for each modal dialog different width size without touching .CSS. Because every modal window has .modal-dialog class and I cant change the name because it will be created with modal window.

Is there any way to do with **`AttributeModifier`** ?

```java
public class MainPanel extends Panel {

    private final ModalDialog modalDialog;

    public MainPanel(String id, IModel<String> headingIdx, IModel<String> collapseIdx) {
        super(id);
        setOutputMarkupId(true);
        modalDialog = new ModalDialog("modalDialog");
        modalDialog.add(new DefaultTheme());
        modalDialog.trapFocus();
        modalDialog.closeOnEscape();
        add(modalDialog);

        add(new AjaxLink<Void>("showModalDialog") {
            @Override
            public void onClick(AjaxRequestTarget target) {
                modalDialog.setContent(new ModalPanel("content", MainPanel.this){
                    @Override
                    protected void close(AjaxRequestTarget target) {
                        modalDialog.close(target);
                    }
                });
                modalDialog.open(target);
            }
        });
        add(modalDialog);
    }
}
```

```css
.modal-header {
    font-weight: bold;
    border: none;
}

.modal-dialog {
    border-radius: 5px;
    pointer-events: all;
}

.modal-dialog .modal-dialog-content {
    /* flex children */
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}

.modal-dialog-overlay.current-focus-trap .modal-dialog-content {
    /* resize the dialog with current focus only, otherwise the resize handle shows through on Firefox */
    resize: both;
}

.modal-dialog .modal-dialog-form {
    /* size */
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;

    /* flex in parent */
    flex: 1;

    /* flex children */
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}

.modal-dialog .modal-dialog-header {
    border-radius: 5px 5px 0px 0px;
    background: #ffb158;
    margin: 0;
    padding-top: 4px;
    text-align: center;
}

.modal-dialog .modal-dialog-body {
    /* size */
    flex: 1;
    overflow-y: auto;

    padding: 20px;
}

.modal-dialog .modal-dialog-footer {
    padding: 5px;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can add a custom CSS class to each ModalWindow:

```
modalDialog.add(AttributeAppender.append("class", "custom-1"));
```

Then in your .css file you can add CSS rules, for example:

```
.modal-dialog.custom-1 {
   width: 1234px;
}
```

or

```
.modal-dialog.custom-1 .modal-dialog-content {
   width: 1234px;
}
```

It depends which element of the modal window you need to modify.